# Why am I getting an incorrect value for the file size in my script?

Tags: bash

I'm trying to get the size of files in a bash script on OS X.  If I explicitly specify the file's name, I get the correct answer.  If I try to do this looping thing, I get an incorrect answer.  This bash script is part of a folder action in Automator and I need to not set the name explicitly because the contents of the folder will change.

This gives me the correct answer:

```
function get_file_size {
    filesize1=$(stat -f%z "/Users/jcoulson/Nexus Transfer/Test.mpeg")
    echo $filesize1
}
for f in "/Users/jcoulson/Nexus Transfer/"
do
    get_file_size
done
```

This gives me an answer of 136:

```
function get_file_size {
    filesize1=$(stat -f%z "$f")
    echo $filesize1
}
for f in "/Users/jcoulson/Nexus Transfer/"
do
    get_file_size
done
```

**EDIT:** The problem must be with stat.  If I just put `echo "found something"` in place of get_file_size, I see the text echo.

Comment: It's better to pass the file name as an argument than to rely on `f` as a global variable: `get_file_size "$f"`, with `$1` replacing `$f` inside the definition of `get_file_size`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variables are OK, but you forgot the `*` wildcard, so you'r stat'ing directory instead of file

```
function get_file_size {
    filesize1=$(stat -f%z "$f")
    echo $filesize1
}
for f in "/Users/jcoulson/Nexus Transfer/*"
do
    get_file_size
done
```

Comment: `stat: /Users/jcoulson/NexusTransfer/*: stat: No such file or directory` after making that change.

Comment: This is what I needed to do in addition to removing the quotation marks around the path.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is

```
function get_file_size {
    filesize1=$(stat -f%z "$1")
    echo $filesize1
}
for f in "/Users/jcoulson/Nexus Transfer/"
do
    get_file_size $f
done
```

$1 refers to the first parameter, and putting $f after get_file_size will call it with $f as the first param

Comment: That makes sense!  But if I do that, I'm told `stat: No such file or directory`.  If I surround `$f` in quotes, I get the 136 answer.

Comment: Okay, I eliminated the space in the directory name and it still is telling me 136.

Comment: Hey, I actually discovered that I can either pass the value as a parameter like this or just refer to it by the variable's name.  So, you taught me how to pass a parameter between functions in bash scripts.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone stumbling across this in the future, here's my finished script:

```
function get_file_size {
    filesize1=$(stat -f%z "$f")
    echo $filesize1
}
for f in /Users/jcoulson/NexusTransfer/*
do
    get_file_size
done
```